# Обернуть блок в тег а

Tags: jquery

Подскажите почему не получается обернуть блок с текстом в тег а?

```
<div class="trigger_list">
  <img src="/upload/2e589.png" class="trigger_img">
  <span class="trigger_text">Текст для примера</span>
</div>

var r = $(".trigger_list:contains('Текст')")
$(".trigger_list:contains('Текст')").wrap( function(){
   if($(this).text() == r)
     return "<a href='/index.php'></a>";
   else
     return "";
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.text()
```

```js
var r = $(".trigger_list:contains('Текст')").text();

console.log(r);

$(".trigger_list:contains('Текст')").wrap( function(){
   if($(this).text() === r){
     return "<a href='/index.php'></a>";
   }else {
     return "";
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="trigger_list">
  <img src="/upload/2e589.png" class="trigger_img">
  <span class="trigger_text">Текст для примера</span>
</div>
```

Или просто

```
$(".trigger_list:contains('Текст')").wrap( "<a href='/index.php'></a>" );
```

потому как `:contains` итак проверяет наличие `"Текст"`.

А если только текст обернуть, то:

```
$(".trigger_list span:contains('Текст')").wrap("<a href='/index.php'></a>");
```

но, думаю, это и так понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще так сделать

```js
function wrap() {
  // Достаем исходный текст
  var text = $('.trigger_text').text();
  // Убираем текст, иначе будет дублирование
  $('.trigger_text').text('');
  // Делаем обертку
  $('.trigger_text').append('<a href="/index.php">' + text + '</a>');
}
wrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="trigger_list">
  <img src="/upload/2e589.png" class="trigger_img">
  <span class="trigger_text">Текст для примера</span>
</div>
```